# Apache Camel HTTP / HTTP4 ignores Content-Type header

Tags: json, http-headers, apache-camel

I'm trying to send an http call through Apache Camel using camel-http.

When I set the header Content-Type it ignores the header and doesn't include it in the call.

I have tried to set the header has follows:

`exchange.getOut().setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'),`

and

`exchange.getOut().setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, 'application/json');`

I have also tried using camel-http and camel-http4 and it doesn't work with any of them.

Since I have to, mandatorily, send the Content-Type header, How can I force Camel-HTTP to include it?

---

Note: I'm also setting other headers the same way that are correctly send with the call, it's just the Content-Type the one that doesn't work

Comment: Have you seen this discussion? http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Http4-Set-Header-Content-Type-not-passing-through-to-the-HTTP-Request-td5746414.html

Comment: As a workaround, setting the body to an empty json document, `{}`, camel-http autodetects that the content type is application/json and sets the proper Content-Type header.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like the following to set the Content-Type:

```
<setHeader headerName="Content-Type">

        <constant>application/json</constant>

</setHeader>
```

This will work to set the Content-Type.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing, but if the body is empty camel-http/camel-http4 automatically removes the Content-Type header.

Comment: You have to set the body after you set the Content-Type header. Like the following:
 `<setBody>
<constant>{
json text for body here
}</constant>
</setBody>`